# If statement inside foreach loop to format specific column

Tags: php, html

This is my current code to fetch the data:

```
<thead>
<?php
foreach ($fields as $val) {
$fieldname=$val->name;
echo "<th>".$fieldname."</th>";
}
?>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<?php
foreach ($rows as $data){       
echo "<td>".$data."</td>";
?>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Some of the fields are Id, Title, Amount, and so on. I would like to format the specific column 'Title' so it will become a link.
Thank you very much.

I tried If Statements like:

```
if($rows==$rows['AMOUNT']){
//format here
}
```

but it yields no advancement.
The If Statement works, however, with the fieldnames if I want to,say, change the font-style of a single column.

Comment: So, what have you tried in order to get the desired result?

Comment: missing <table> <tr> tag.

Comment: show the structure of `$rows` is it index array or associative array ?

Comment: this is the part where i fetch my data: while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

Comment: missing `}` inside `<tr>...</tr>`

Comment: how looks `$rows` array? is it Associative or Numeric array?

Comment: sorry about the missing tags. the table is working alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment `$rows` is Associative array

in your case you need to get both array value and array key the foreach syntax of getting key and value is

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
```

try with this checking the **key** of array and you can use `elseif` also if you want to make check on another field

```
foreach ($rows as $key => $data)
{       
   if($key == 'Title'){
     echo "<td><a href='yourlink'>".$data."</a></td>";
   }
   else{
     echo "<td>".$data."</td>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use associative array check **key value** to identify column:

```
<?php
foreach ($rows as $key => $data){ 
    if($key == 'AMOUNT')
        //format here
    elseif($key == 'TITLE')
        //format here
    else
        echo "<td>".$data."</td>";
}
?>
```